# How do I send duplicate query strings using requests module in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `request url` which accepts duplicate query string to send data. The format is:

```
http://<rest_url>/resource?scheduledate=2018-02-25&scheduledate=2018-03-02
```

This retrieves the data between two dates. The issue now is how to send the query string. I'm using `requests`. My code is

```
var options = {
            url: rest_url ,
 // this will not work since you cant have duplicate keys
            qs:{
              'scheduledDate':moment().add(-1,'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
              'scheduledDate':moment().add(1,'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            },

            auth: {
              'bearer': token[0]['access_token']
            }
          }

          // **************** Rest Request to API *************************

          request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
```

How do I now send the duplicate query strings? I tried doing

```
  var yesterday = moment().add(-1,'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var OneDayinFuture=moment().add(1,'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var query_string =yesterday+ "&scheduledDate="+OneDayinFuture; 
   var options = {
            url: rest_url ,
            qs:{
              'scheduledDate':query_string               
            },
            auth: {
              'bearer': token[0]['access_token']
            }
          }
```

The endpoint throws an error.

I know there might be an option where I can just append the `query_string` with URL but that wouldn't work as I do recursively follow the next page link. So, it has to be a query string unless there is a definite way out of it. I am kind of stuck here.

Comment: Would it make sense to rename the parameters to scheduledateStart and scheduledateEnd? I have seen that approach before.

Comment: unfortunately it is a third party api so i don't know have any authority.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the two values in an array and pass `{ indices: false }` for the `qsStringifyOptions` option:

```
var options = {
  url: rest_url,
  qs: {
    scheduledDate: [ date1, date2 ],
  },
  qsStringifyOptions: { indices: false },
  //...
};
```

This is documented in the [Stringifying](https://github.com/ljharb/qs/blob/037f3686e8f8eee456cf958c39ffd8a967d4ead5/README.md#stringifying) section of the qs README:

> When arrays are stringified, by default they are given explicit
>   indices:
>
> ```
> qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c', 'd'] });
> // 'a[0]=b&a[1]=c&a[2]=d'
> ```
>
> You may override this by setting the `indices` option to `false`:
>
> ```
> qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c', 'd'] }, { indices: false });
> // 'a=b&a=c&a=d'
> ```

Comment: Brilliant !! i tried using `stringify` but i didnt know you can set it false.  Thanks Jordan !! you saved me . It works great